# Magento 2 module creation - Enabling without command line

Tags: php, magento

I have purchased a hosting which supports magento 2. I use cpanel to create DB and upload files and installed it successfully. Am trying to learn module creation by this tutorial...

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

When i encounter the following line...

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

which was supposed to be executed via commandline for the new module to get registered... i struckup.... from the very beginning i did not use commandline for anything here and am not comfortable with that too. Just wondering if there is a alternate way in magento to enable a custom module that i develop.

Note: the hosting i have doesnot offer ssh access so there is no way i can browse to that page and run that command.

Pls help me understand this... am new to magento development...

Comment: Follow this link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125064/how-to-install-module-magento-2-dont-need-run-command-line-bin-magento-setupup